# Is there a way to bypass all security checks in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm coming from the PHP world. The framework I used most is Symfony which is heavily based on ideas from Spring. One if its bundles called JMSSecurityExtraBundle supports a role `ROLE_IDDQD` that you can activate via [configuration](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/configuration). Authenticating with that role would effectively bypass all the security checks — be those Web security constraints or constraints directly on methods of classes in the domain layer.

Since security related tests needed a user with a particular role to be authenticated, I would authenticate a user programmatically creating an authentication object and passing it to the security context. That way I could test security constraints directly on the domain code without involing any UI.

Since a lot of domain methods would be secured, it would prevent me from setting up fixtures for some of the tests because the currently authenticated user wouldn't have enough permissions to do that. This is where I started using `ROLE_IDDQD` — I created a method that would take a function that could do anything in the domain layer bypassing any security constraints:

```php
$user = $this->iddqd(function () {
    return $this->userManager->save($this->aUser());
});
```

That method would remember the current authentication, reauthenticate with `ROLE_IDDQD`, execute the function passed in and then restore the remembered authentication.

I'm migrating the app to Spring and looking for a way to do the same with Spring. I couldn't find any mention of `ROLE_IDDQD`, so I guess that part wasn't based on Spring Security. Are there any other means to replicate this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem a long time ago. Here's how I did it.

In my architectures, I usually have a repository layer that abstracts away database access and a manager layer above the repository layer that enforces domain logic.

The problem was in my approach to testing. I tried to use managers to set up test data. I now do it directly using repositories and there's no need for hacks like IDDQD roles and such.

So, basically, I use repositories to populate databases with test data, and then I hit managers to test domain logic in them.

Answer (score 0):

Spring security has a concept of Anonymous user with automatically assigned role "ROLE_ANONYMOUS". You can look for more information [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/anonymous.html)

Comment: All users of the system must be authenticated, so the anonymous role doesn't apply here.

Comment: So you want some mechanism to add roles dynamically and test your domains and then reset those roles to least priviledge one. Right ?

Comment: I want a way to bypass security checks on methods that require a particular role even though the currently logged in user doesn't have that role. I need this only for testing. And I don't care if that's done using roles or some other ways exist.